# Python - Large File Name RENAME ERROR (Win Error 3)

Tags: python

I am getting the following error in "python" when I try  `os.rename` in Windows, Python 3 (spyder).

```
os.rename('123456789012345678901234567890123456.jpg', '1234567890123456789012345678901234567.jpg')
```

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path
>   specified: '123456789012345678901234567890123456.jpg' ->
>   '1234567890123456789012345678901234567.jpg'

The file name above got 36 characters.

When I try with 35 character filename then I am NOT getting the error and rename works fine.

```
os.rename('12345678901234567890123456789012345.jpg', '123456789012345678901234567890123456.jpg')
```

I've also tried with FULL path C:....\filename in the source and target file for rename but it works with the file name till 35 characters (full path it has got 254 characters including file name).  When I try with 255 characters (ie., full path including file name with 36 characters), then I am getting Win Error 3. If the file doesn't exists (really), then I got Win Error 2.
I am looking for a generic solution so that I can apply this for all large file named files.

Comment: What version of Python 3? I thought since somewhere around 3.4, it was using the Unicode APIs that have a max length of 32K instead of 260, but maybe not. Anyway, the only workaround (assuming you actually need paths longer than Windows will allow with POSIX-style paths) is to use explicit NT-style paths with `\\?\…` format. (This also means always using absolute paths.)

Comment: I tried both full path and relative path. Both failed as I mentioned in my query.  Instead of just posting the question as 'I got this error', I have done some analysis starting with manually updating file name from 8 characters to 36 characters, tried understanding the full path length etc. When I tried to move the file to the root directory it worked. That means the Windows full path length is the issue EVEN-THOUGH I specify the relative path/file name.

Comment: Did you not read the part about “explicit NT-style paths with `\\?\…` format? A path starting with `C` is obviously not starting with `\\?\`.

Comment: Also, instead of telling me all the work you did( why not answer the question: which version of Python 3?

Comment: Version is Python 3.5.  What is wrong in providing answer to the path I tried. I tried both relative, absolute path and also \\style. Finally "nosklo"'s answered confirmed me the answer.

Comment: If you use ` \\?\` paths, you get 260 characters per directory, up to 65535 total for the full path, instead of just 260 characters for the full path. If you want an actual solution, instead of just to know why what you're doing doesn't work, that's the solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that windows has a path size limit of 260 characters, when adding the path plus filename. If you move your file closer to the root, it will be renamed just fine.

See [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation) for more information on the subject.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I guessed the answer earlier. Instead of just posting the question as 'I got this error', I have done some analysis starting with file name from 8 characters to 36 characters, tried understanding the full path length etc., Thanks for confirming the total length is the issue here. I tried moving to root folders and the big file worked fine as expected.  Thanks for the update.

Comment: From the documentation linked above, I understand the 'length' restriction removed? I would like to get possible solution even the full directory + file name is 260+ (as I may not aware the real life situations). Do we have any solution without moving to root?

Comment: please note that earlier I got Win Error 3 when I just passed the file name with 36 characters (without adding the full path). Looks like the os.rename looks into the fullpath even when you just give the relative path (as I mentioned in my initial question I tried two ways and both did not work with 36 character file name).

Comment: @user9615218 exactly, the limitation is full path, even if you don't pass it. The solution we used here was to stop using directories and filenames to store data.